# How to find nearest hospital in google maps

Tags: google-maps

i have an google maps which shows a path of dynamic latitude and longitude,i have an requirement to show total number of hospital,total number of schools in that path(Please see the image for reference).
[google maps image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0tEn.png)

Is there an option in google maps API to fetch this data ?

Comment: I don't think Google Maps APIs expose this data. You can try Places API, but it doesn't return all possible hospitals or schools, only the prominent ones.

Comment: ok @xomena any other way to get this data

Comment: Just to add up to what @xomena said, you can use [Places Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) that lets you search for places within a specified area.  You can rank the results by prominence or distance

Comment: ok will check @jabamataro